# Please I need solution about Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Please someone help me to spot out the errors here from this code syntax.

I've been trying to sort this issue out all day but I've been getting from one issue to another.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.ome.allfreecurrencyconverter">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<activity
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">

    <activity
        android:name="com.ome.allfreecurrencyconverter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.ome.allfreecurrencyconverter.Activity_conversion_listview"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent" >

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.ome.allfreecurrencyconverter.Activity_Introactivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent" >

    </activity>

  </activity>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your activity is not inside application syntax!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have Activities tags inside the Application Tag not Activities tag inside another Activity Tag, so you need to replace your first Activity opening Tag by Application.

Your manifest should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.ome.allfreecurrencyconverter" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

//This is the correct opening tag
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">

    <activity
        android:name="com.ome.allfreecurrencyconverter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.ome.allfreecurrencyconverter.Activity_conversion_listview"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.ome.allfreecurrencyconverter.Activity_Introactivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">

    </activity>

  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: No worries, you can also remove `'tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent"` . You shouldn't need that. Also if it helped you, could you accept my answer?

Comment: Working fine now

Answer (score 0):

You have added the activity in wrong Tag. You should have

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.ome.allfreecurrencyconverter" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">

    <activity
        android:name="com.ome.allfreecurrencyconverter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.ome.allfreecurrencyconverter.Activity_conversion_listview"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.ome.allfreecurrencyconverter.Activity_Introactivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">

    </activity>

</application>
```